# iOS Objective C - Getting NSDate of a particular day

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

i have stuck up to NSDate Calculations any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance. following is the functional requirement in **objective-c**

How to get NSDate of a particular day (for selecting days i have check boxes from Monday to Sunday).

I will choose start date i.e NSDate from picker view for example i have chosen 16-08-17.

Then will enter days count for example 10days.

Then i'll be choosing days with checkbox i.e i will be having 7 checkbox's for 7 days Monday - Sunday. for example **i have chosen Wednesday and Thursday** (choosing "**Wednesday" will be mandatory as start date 16-08-17 is Wednesday**).

If i hit save action, have to calculate end date(end date to be in NSDate) 10 days to 16-08-17. **here comes the main logic 10 days will only Wednesday's and Saturdays**  so the has to be calculated and result to be 20-09-17.

```
16-08-2017 Wed
19-08-2017 Sat
23-08-2017 Wed
26-08-2017 Sat
02-09-2017 Wed
06-09-2017 Sat
13-09-2017 Wed
16-09-2017 Sat
20-09-2017 Wed
23-09-2017 Sat
```

if days count is 9 days result should be 20-09-2017.

Comment: Look into NSDateComponents. You can build NSDates from that by settings the components (Day, month, year, hour, minute, etc manually.

Answer (score -1):

```
 NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateFormatter *sdateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [sdateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSDate *sdate=[sdateFormatter dateFromString:anstrdate];
    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:sdate];
    NSInteger todayWeekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
    enum Weeks {
        SUNDAY = 1,
        MONDAY,
        TUESDAY,
        WEDNESDAY,
        THURSDAY,
        FRIDAY,
        SATURDAY
    };
    NSInteger days = 0;
    if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Sunday"])
    {
        days=1;
        sundaySelected=YES;
        atleastOneSelected= YES;
    }
    if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Monday"])
    {
        mondaySelected=YES;
        atleastOneSelected= YES;
        days=2;
    }
   if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Tuesday"])
    {
        tuesdaySelected=YES;
        atleastOneSelected= YES;
        days=3;
    }
if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Wednesday"])
    {
        wednesdaySelected=YES;
        atleastOneSelected= YES; 
        days=4;
    }
if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Thursday"])
    {
        thursdaySelected=YES;
        atleastOneSelected= YES;
        days=5;
    }
if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Friday"])
    {
        fridaySelected=YES;
        atleastOneSelected= YES;
        days=6;
    }
if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Saturday"])
    {
        sundaySelected=YES;
        atleastOneSelected= YES;
        days=7;
    }
    NSString *str=self.andaysTxt.text;
    NSInteger noofdays=[str integerValue];
    NSInteger moveDays=days-todayWeekday;

    while (moveDays<=0) {
        moveDays+=((noofdays-1)*7);
    }

    NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
    components.day=moveDays;
    NSCalendar *calendar=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDate* newEndDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:sdate options:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",newEndDate);
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    _anendDateTxt.placeholder=@"End Date";
    self.anendDateTxt.text = [formatter stringFromDate:newEndDate];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        NSDateFormatter *sdateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [sdateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        NSDate *sdate=[sdateFormatter dateFromString:anstrdate];
        NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:sdate];
        NSInteger todayWeekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
        enum Weeks {
            SUNDAY = 1,
            MONDAY,
            TUESDAY,
            WEDNESDAY,
            THURSDAY,
            FRIDAY,
            SATURDAY
        };
        NSInteger days = 0;
        if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Sunday"])
        {
            days=1;
            sundaySelected=YES;
            atleastOneSelected= YES;
        }
        if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Monday"])
        {
            mondaySelected=YES;
            atleastOneSelected= YES;
            days=2;
        }
       if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Tuesday"])
        {
            tuesdaySelected=YES;
            atleastOneSelected= YES;
            days=3;
        }
    if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Wednesday"])
        {
            wednesdaySelected=YES;
            atleastOneSelected= YES; 
            days=4;
        }
    if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Thursday"])
        {
            thursdaySelected=YES;
            atleastOneSelected= YES;
            days=5;
        }
    if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Friday"])
        {
            fridaySelected=YES;
            atleastOneSelected= YES;
            days=6;
        }
    if([anstartdate isEqualToString:@"Saturday"])
        {
            sundaySelected=YES;
            atleastOneSelected= YES;
            days=7;
        }
        NSString *str=self.andaysTxt.text;
        NSInteger noofdays=[str integerValue];
        NSInteger moveDays=days-todayWeekday;

        while (moveDays<=0) {
            moveDays+=((noofdays-1)*7);
        }

        NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
        components.day=moveDays;
        NSCalendar *calendar=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        NSDate* newEndDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:sdate options:0];
        NSLog(@"%@",newEndDate);
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        _anendDateTxt.placeholder=@"End Date";
        self.anendDateTxt.text = [formatter stringFromDate:newEndDate];
```

I want to run this in a loop, the above code is functional only a single day is selected if 18/08/2017 as start date which comes on "Friday" and days count is "10"  end date is calculated as 20/10/2017. that is correct if select multiple days i.e For example "Friday" and "Saturday" the end date should be calculated as 16/09/2017 because the 10th day is completing on 16/09/2017 from 18/08/2017.

Comment: i want to run this in loop, the above code is functional only i single day is selected, if 18/08/2017 as start date which comes on "Friday" and days count is "10"  end date is calculated as 20/10/2017. that is correct if select multiple days i.e For example "Friday" and "Saturday" the end date should be calculated as 16/09/2017 because 10th day is completing on 16/09/2017 from 18/08/2017.